# Gridview rowdatabound access data items vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I am trying to an ImageUrl to an image in a Template Field in GridView but keep getting the error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on this line:

Dim imagePath As String = rowView("image_path")

I've never done this before on a GridView but had it working on a ListView.

Thanks for any help heres my code:

**.APSX**

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gvImages" DataKeyNames="id" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="None">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="imageId" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="imageFile" runat="server"></asp:Image>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
Protected Sub gvImages_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvImages.RowDataBound

    Dim rowView As DataRowView = CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)

    Dim imagePath As String = rowView("image_path")

    Dim strImageUrl As String = "~/admin/images/cases/" & Request.QueryString("uid") & "/" & imagePath

    Dim imageFile As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image = CType(e.Row.FindControl("imageFile"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)
    imageFile.ImageUrl = strImageUrl

End Sub
```

Comment: are you sure rowView("image_path") is not returning DBNULL.

Comment: It holds the name of an image so to double check I just removed the image template field and added image_path to a databound field and it displays an image name. so that can't be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to check that its a data row and not the header row

Try this

```
Protected Sub gvImages_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvImages.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim rowView As DataRowView = CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)

        Dim imagePath As String = rowView("image_path")

        Dim strImageUrl As String = "~/admin/images/cases/" & Request.QueryString("uid") & "/" & imagePath

        Dim imageFile As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image = CType(e.Row.FindControl("imageFile"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)
        imageFile.ImageUrl = strImageUrl

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, thanks Nicky, thats sorted it, I had seen something similar when searching but didn't realise it was a MUST have. Thanks. J.

Comment: I've been tripped up by this one plenty of times in the past so no problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Dim imagePath As String = e.rowView("image_path").ToString()
```

If the table binded with the grid has column "image_path", then instead use an easier way....

**`<asp:Image id="img1" runat="server" imageUrl = '<%#Eval("image_path")%>' />`**

If you want to build some custome string

```
imageurl = '<%# String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", Eval("Name1"), Eval("Name2"), Session["abc"],Request["abc"]) %>'
```

Comment: nope, not working either, I get an intellisense error saying rowView is not a member of.... but if I take off the e. the intellisense error goes, but I still get the same error on this line in a browser.

Comment: Hi AmRan, yeah i got that working fine, but i am learning .net and would like to know how to do it from code behind as i'm sure i would have to do this in the future.