# How to download image/pdf file from database using Gridview's linkbutton?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, asp.net-3.5, download

Here is my problem. I have a user control that will download a binary file (image, pdf etc.) using a link button in gridview.

```
<asp:GridView Visible="true" ID="GridView1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="File Name"/>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="DownloadFile" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="DeleteFile"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub DownloadFile(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim id As Integer = Integer.Parse(TryCast(sender, LinkButton).CommandArgument)
    Dim bytes As Byte()
    Dim fileName As String, contentType As String

    Using con As New SqlConnection(DataSource.ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "select FileName, PatImage, FileType from DB where Id=@Id"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id)
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                sdr.Read()
                bytes = DirectCast(sdr("PatImage"), Byte())
                contentType = sdr("FileType").ToString()
                fileName = sdr("FileName").ToString()
            End Using
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.ContentType = contentType
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName)
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

But this is not working if  I have an `UpdatePanel` in my parent aspx page. So i googled and I found an answer; that is to place a code in RowDataBound:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    Dim lb As LinkButton = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lnkDownload"), LinkButton )
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me.Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb)
End Sub
```

And a new error occurred. That is I can't find my linkButton inside my GridView using my code in my RowDataBound.

So i googled again, and i found out that i should add a property to my aspx page `ClientIDMode="AutoID"`. But this is only working on framework 4.x. And I couldn't do that 'cause im currently using 3.5. Are there any remedies in my current situation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232214/gridview-rowdatabound-access-data-items-vb

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Before the GridView control can be rendered, each row in the control must be bound to a record in the data source. The RowDataBound event is raised when a data row (represented by a GridViewRow object) is bound to data in the GridView control. This enables you to provide an event-handling method that performs a custom routine, such as modifying the values of the data bound to the row, whenever this event occurs.

Comment: A GridViewRowEventArgs object is passed to the event-handling method, which enables you to access the properties of the row being bound. To access a specific cell in the row, use the Cells property of the GridViewRow object contained in the Row property of the GridViewRowEventArgs object. You can determine which row type (header row, data row, and so on) is being bound by using the RowType property.

Comment: what will i do first with my code? I'm confused with your explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A already found an answer, I just changed my RowDataBound content, refer to the code:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim LButton = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lnkDownload"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)
        Dim scriptManager__1 = ToolkitScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me.Page)
        If scriptManager__1 IsNot Nothing Then
            scriptManager__1.RegisterPostBackControl(LButton)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```