# Changing a columns contents in a GridView from VB code

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am displaying a grid of data which includes a users name and profile pic etc.
If they haven’t uploaded a profile picture I have set the code below to set imgPic.ImageUrl = "~/files/images/blankProfilePic.png"

However, this works only for the 1st page of 6 pages of data displayed.. As soon as you switch to the 2nd page I get the missing picture icon as the code below is only working for the initial page displayed.
I need to change this code to work on every page as it is only called when the page loads.

VB CODE

---

```
Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete

    Dim acc As New accounts(Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey)

    If acc.region = "North East" Then
        For Each r As GridViewRow in gdvNorthEast.Rows
            If r.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                Dim imgPic As Image
                imgPic = r.Cells(4).FindControl("imgProfilePic")
                If imgPic.ImageUrl = "~/catalog/images/"                                                                                                                                        
                    imgPic.ImageUrl = "~/files/images/blankProfilePic.png"
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    End If
```

ASP.NET

---

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
     ID="DSLeaderboardNorthEast"
     runat="server"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT tblAccounts.contactName, tblAccounts.profilePic, tblAccounts.minAge, tblAccounts.maxAge, tblAccounts.AccountID, tblAccounts.region
                    FROM tblAccounts 
                    WHERE tblAccounts.region='North East' 
                    ORDER BY tblAccounts.contactName ">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="gdvNorthEast" width="100%" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" DataKeyNames="accountID" DataSourceID="DSLeaderboardNorthEast" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgProfilePic" AlternateText="Players profile picture" runat="server" width="100px" height="100px" ImageUrl='<%# "~/catalog/images/" &  Eval("ProfilePic").ToString %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="contactName" HeaderText="Player Name" />     
        <asp:BoundField DataField="minAge" HeaderText="Won" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="maxAge" HeaderText="Lost" />
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hypMessage" runat="server" CssClass="nyroModalMsg" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/sendLeaderboardMessage.aspx?" & "&aID=" & Eval("accountID").ToString %>'>Msg</asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gridview rowdatabound access data items vb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232214/gridview-rowdatabound-access-data-items-vb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreach loop for assigning default image should be reusable method.

Use `PageIndexChanged` event handler to call the same reusable method.

**Update**:
Since the above option is not helping, follow [this post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/rowdatabound-event-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net/)

```
    //RowDataBound Event  
protected void gdvNorthEast_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
{  
    //Checking the RowType of the Row  
    if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)  
    {  
        //your logic goes here without foreach loop  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Ah right.. that makes sense.. I'll go research PageIndexChanged. I tried it with Page_LoadComplete but it didn't work.. I was almost there ;-)

Comment: Sorry if I'm posting in wrong place .. tricky on my  but I can't get it going still with Pageindexchanged as mentioned above. Any further help is appreciated.

Comment: It's definitely going to the subroutine when you change page but the code won't work for any page but first.

Comment: Also I noticed you are using single = to compare image URL. Is it working ? == for comparison = for assignment..

Comment: Yeah It's VB I'm trying to do this in, so just one '='

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232214/gridview-rowdatabound-access-data-items-vb

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Gridview_RowDataBound` event to make the function of substitution instead use a for instruction

Comment: You mean "use a pageload for" ?

Comment: Thanks @fabioTos I'm not entirely sure how to do that. A lot of this code was written for me as I'm just learning. Could you please tell me exactly where to add a For?

Comment: He meant you have to use RowDataBound event instead of Page_LoadComplete event. This is another choice.

Comment: I will mate cheers. I’m still struggling though.
I set up  Public Sub gdvNorthEast_PageIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) and in the grindview control I put onpageindexchanged="gdvNorthEast_PageIndexChanged"

But again when you change page, the same thing happens.

Comment: Try to put inside Sub gdvNorthEast_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) event and add onrowdatabound attribute on your gridview. Inside this event you don't need to make the for each cicly but you can take the row information using the parameter e

Comment: I'm a bit lost sorry. I've added onrowdatabound="" but not sure what to put in the quotes. For instance still need onpageindexchanged?

Comment: Onrowdatabound="gdvNorthEast_RowDataBound". If you use this kind of solution you don't need onpageindecchanged event